# WordPress template showing black images instead of the url image only on Safari browser

Tags: html, wordpress, cross-browser

My WordPress template called [BoxWP](https://wordpress.org/themes/boxwp/) is showing black images instead of the url image I load using `<img src>`.

This happens only in my template and only on Safari browser. I checked on Chrome and Opera, no problems there. I checked on a separate `.html` file on Safari with `<img src="...">` and same url to load image and it works. So the problem is only on Safari browser in combination with the template called 'boxwp'.

The file I use to show the image is `content-single.php`. I just put `<img src="...">` tag and load the url.

Try to load this image url in the file I mentioned:

> https://gloimg.gbtcdn.com/soa/gb/pdm-product-pic/Electronic/2019/05/20/goods_img-v2/20190520141054_13268.jpg

I use Safari browser on Macintosh. You can download the theme here: https://wordpress.org/themes/boxwp/.

Any thoughts what might be the issue?

Comment: Can you provide an example file such as via jsfiddle where this problem is reproducible? Are there any errors you're seeing in the Safari console?

Comment: no error on console! https://jsfiddle.net/v4k8o1pw/ Thats the code i run inside the content-single.php

Comment: Did you write that code? You don't need the </img> tag at the end.

Comment: Yes i know i was just trying to fix it and i changed it /> is the right one i understand

Comment: i get this https://imgur.com/T4QiHRQ instead of the image

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing, but loading an image is one of the most basic things a browser can do and I really doubt it's a browser specific issue and may be more than the other browsers are fixing something you're doing wrong. Can you provide code that reproduces the problem? If this is Wordpress there could also be a plugin doing something with images such as a lightbox that is causing issues.

Comment: Its the theme in combination with the safari. I cant reproduce it because its the theme that is doing it. If you download the theme then install it in wordpress and then add the img src with the specific image url i gave you here it will show the black square instead of the image...

Comment: What happens when you just add the image through the normal Wordpress post editor instead of using RAW HTML.